# Can't set state in React using hooks

Tags: reactjs, spotify

I'm working on a fairly simple app to learn React Hooks and I got stuck. I want to fetch and display data from specific Spotify playlist. So far, this is my component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function SongsList() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ songs: [] });
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            const result = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZEVXbMDoHDwVN2tF/tracks', {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Bearer sometoken'
                    }
                }
            )
            setData(result.data.items);
            console.log(result.data.items);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {isLoading ? (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    {data.songs.map(song => (
                        <li key={song.track.id}>
                            <p>{song.track.artist}</p>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </div>
            )
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default SongsList;
```

This code throws an error saying `TypeError: data.songs is undefined` and I can't understand why is that. Please note that in my `fetchData` function I have a log from my console tu ensure that I at least fetch any data: `console.log(result.data.items);`. It gives me the correct output:
[image: my console log output]

But my `data` in `useState` output seems to be never setted or setted wrong. Can you please help me to understand what is wrong about my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are setting an _array_ as content of `data` state (`result.data.items`) so probably your code should be `data.map(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the `data` right way. You have declared `data` as an object which contains `songs`. You should set `songs` like:

```
setData({ songs: result.data.items });
```

And this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your component is mounted before the request is made, you should also check for the presence of the data before rendering. like below:

```
{ data && data.songs.map(song => (
   <li key={song.track.id}>
       <p>{song.track.artist}</p>
   </li>
   )) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this  `setData({songs: result.data.items});`

Because you are defining your `songs` array in object.